# Difference between Java Concurrency, Akka and RxJava?

Tags: java, concurrency, akka, rx-java

Today I found that, for concurrency in java we have good framework like `Akka` and I also found that, there is a reactive programming frameworks like `RxJava` for performing `multithreading` in application. But I'm still confused! Why are both better than `Java Concurrency` framework?

Nowadays reactive programing is mature topic, and most languages have support for `Functional Reactive Programing` like `Netflix` provide APIs regarding `Reactive programming` for more than one language. `Rxjava` is one of the api that is used for `java`, `scala` etc. According to `RxJava`, they internally use actors for maintaining `multithreading` and `Akka` also uses `Actors` for `multithreading` programming.

So, what is the difference between `Akka` and `Reactive Programming` approach and why they are good from `Java Concurrency` ?

Comment: Unclear; and ultimately, choosing this or that solution depends on your needs.

Comment: ok, But which approach is good, reactive programming, akka or java concurrency ? because they all provide `multithreading`.

Comment: There is no general "good approach"; just go with what you are familiar with and/or want to do. Personally, I just use what the JDK provides since it is good enough for my needs, and that's about it.

Comment: @fge the thing is that, why `akka` and `reactive programming` is popular in now day's? most of the good developers suggest to follow reactive approach.

Comment: Well, I don't know whether I'm a "good developer" but I wouldn't recommend any of them, because I don't use them and don't need them. And as far as concurrency is concerned, you want to (buy and) read "Java Concurrency In Practice" by Brian Goetz.

Comment: yes i have this book, this book is really awesome, and i am not said like that you are not a `good developer`. sorry if i heart you. but evolution is the part of development. and i just still want to know that, why we preferred them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to Mathias Doenitz at this point in time RxJava doesn't have back pressure unlike Akkas Reactive Streams implementation. But RxJava seems to be working on adding back pressure.

Both frameworks will be able to interact through the reactive streaming spi. 
So you will be able to do very very similar things. According to Mathias the difference will be that the Akka implementation is based internally on actors, not on multi-threading. And as a result will be more performant.

My source for this information is [a talk](http://spray.io/duse/#/) that Mathias gave last week at the Dutch Scala user group.

edit: I stand corrected wrt back pressure support in RxJava. If you follow Eriks link you can read what back pressure means.

Comment: "According to Mathias Doenitz at this point in time RxJava doesn't have back pressure" That is factually incorrect; https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure

Comment: rxJava2.x has back pressure support.

Comment: RxJava is also not based on multi-threading. Please update the answer to accurately reflect current reality. Appending an edit comment is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Akka Streams being based on actors provides interop between actors and streams, e.g.:

- reading from actor and passing it to streams and
- reading from streams and passing it to actors